# Re: How can I escape meta-characters when I interpolate a variable in Perl's match operator?

Tags: bash, python, perl, regex

The link

[How can I escape meta-characters when I interpolate a variable in Perl's match operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001176)

didn't help me.

I have tried with Python:

```
import os
line='ID_SN=02      MS=DC:A6:32:7E:74:08    S=*     TS=24/11/2020 11:02:30 CET      N=IMC2500       MD=7F:7A:25:43:8F:44    T=LE    P=90@'
cmd1="perl -sni -e 'print unless /^\Q$regex\E$/' -- -regex=%s device_scan.txt" % repr(line)
os.system(cmd1)
```

But `\Q`...`\E` also block interpretation of `\t` but I need to interpret only that. So no row is deleted.

This seems like a rather complicated problem to solve but I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
import os
line='ID_SN=02      MS=DC:A6:32:7E:74:08    S=*     TS=24/11/2020 11:02:30 CET      N=IMC2500       MD=7F:7A:25:43:8F:44    T=LE    P=90@'
cmd1='perl -sni -e \'print unless /^\Q$regex\E$/\' -- -regex=\'%s\' device_scan.txt' % line.replace("'","'\"'\"'")
os.system(cmd1)
```

But I have a question for you @steeldriver. Within of perl variable "$regex" in  this case, there is the possibility that any subvariables starting with "$" or "@" or "%" are expanded?

Answer (score 2):

You could use perl's `-s` flag, which acts similarly to awk's `-v` option

```bsh
perl -i -sne 'print unless /^\Q$regex\E$/' -- -regex="$var" device_scan.txt
```

The `--` following `-e 'body'` is required so that `-regex` is not taken as a *perl* option, it is left for the body.

Also, the `-e` body is now single quoted to keep the perl variable away from the shell

Using @steeldriver's example:

```bsh
$ var='*'
$ perl -sne 'print unless /\Q$regex\E/' -- -regex="$var" <(
    printf '%s\n' foo 'bar * baz' qux
  )
foo
qux
```

---

Another way around it is to use shell parameter expansion to escape the slashes. Clearly this gets messy:

```bsh
perl -ni -e "print unless /^\Q${var//\//\\/}\E$/" device_scan.txt
# ............................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The last solution is rejected. Because if the variable contains `\/` before of the replacement, it generates an error again.

Comment: \Q and \E also block interpretation of \t, but I need to interpret only that. Actually I'm communicating from Python on bash and things get pretty hard to handle. I will modify my question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest (and most robust) way is to *export* the variable into the shell's environment, then access it via the `ENV` hash. That way, you don't need to rely on the shell parsing `$var` *inside* the perl expression and can use single instead of double quotes:

```
$ export var='*'
$ 
$ printf '%s\n' foo \* baz | perl -ne 'print unless /\Q$ENV{"var"}\E/'
foo
baz
```

Comment: Why this `perl -ni -e 'print unless /^\Q$ENV{"var"}\E$/'` works for me and this `perl -ni -e 'print unless /^\QID_SN=02 MS=DC:A6:32:7E:74:08 S=* TS=24/11/2020 11:02:30 CET N=IMC2500 MD=7F:7A:25:43:8F:44 T=LE P=90@\E$/'` not?

Comment: because the regex contains slashes which you use as the regex delimiter

Comment: @glennjackman This is not the answer to my comment. The question is why if I store the content in a variable and expose it with $ENV{"var"} it works, instead with the text in full it doesn't work.

Comment: Because perl is smart about it: any slashes in the variable contents will not be taken as the closing slash. In my last comment, I should have said "The _literal_ regex contains slashes"

Comment: Then what are \Q and \E for if, as you say, the content of the variable is not interpreted?

Comment: You might find it documented in `perldoc perlre` or `perldoc perlop`. What can I say, that's the way it works. Compare `perl -MCwd -E "say 'under home' if cwd() =~ /\Q$HOME\E/"` versus `perl -MCwd -E 'say "under home" if cwd() =~ /\Q$ENV{HOME}\E/'`

Comment: `\Q` is for escaping regex metacharacters. Slash is not one of those.

Comment: AAAHHHHHHHHHHHH, OK. Thank you for this precisation glenn. XD

Comment: @MarioPalumbo you can deal with in-pattern slashes in a similar way as in sed - that is, by using a different pattern delimiter. In sed, it needs to be introduced using a backslash escape like `\%pattern/with/slashes%` whereas in perl you use an `m` to indicate that it's a regex **m**atch ex. `m:pattern/with/slashes:`